# radio button filters in wpf c# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, radio-button

I am working on an Link extractor c# application. that scrape urls according to keyword. Like when a user search the keyword using `txtKeyWords` text box field and hit the search button then he will be able to grab desired Urls on any keyword with open google search operator `"http://www.google.com/search?num=1000&q="`.
Now I am wondering how to add this code 
 `http://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=allinurl:site:.edu` for the sake of grabing only edu links under `rb1.Checked`. Like when user check radio btn1 and enter desired keyword in `txtKeyWords` text box field, then he able to grab query related .edu Links. I have done several tries but unable to do so. Here is the code of `Search Button`

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] ResultsBuffer = new byte[8192];
            string SearchResults = "http://www.google.com/search?num=1000&q=" + txtKeyWords.Text.Trim();
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SearchResults);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string tempString = null;
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = resStream.Read(ResultsBuffer, 0, ResultsBuffer.Length);
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ResultsBuffer, 0, count);
                    sb.Append(tempString);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            string sbb = sb.ToString();

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            html.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
            html.LoadHtml(sbb);
            HtmlNode doc = html.DocumentNode;

            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                //HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
                if (!hrefValue.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("GOOGLE") && hrefValue.ToString().Contains("/url?q=") && hrefValue.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("HTTP://"))
                {
                    int index = hrefValue.IndexOf("&");
                    if (index > 0)
                    {
                        hrefValue = hrefValue.Substring(0, index);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(hrefValue.Replace("/url?q=", ""));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your searches will always use Google, you may want to just use the URL itself to filter.

So you would append your radio button text to the string similar to this...

string SearchResults = "http://www.google.com/search?num=1000&q=" + txtKeyWords.Text.Trim() **+ "&as_sitesearch=" + radioButton1.Text.Trim()**;

which would yield a URL such as this...

https://www.google.com/search?num=1000&q=cars**&as_sitesearch=.edu**

The results should then be filtered by your radio box selection (in this case, .edu).

Now every result *should* contain ".edu"

Hope this helps!

Forgot to mention:  If you need to further filter, use the Google Advanced Search and it will build the URL for you to use...
https://www.google.com/advanced_search

Comment: @ForulaChris Still problem occur. I know you provide a good solution but my problem is assume this is the search `Button` code `string SearchResults = "http://www.google.com/search?num=1000&q=" + txtKeyWords.Text.Trim()` when I assign string value `.edu` to radio button1 and concatenate it with the `search button` code then it shows me the wrong results. I mean it do not return `.edu` results. It pick as a Keyword not as a search operator..Any Solution.??

Comment: Thanks Got it Working Good.